# Search through text word by word

Tags: ruby

I'd like to search through a txt file for a particular word. If I find that word, I'd like to retrieve the word that immediately follows it in the file. If my text file contained:

```
"My name is Jay and I want to go to the store"
```

I'd be searching for the word `"want"`, and would want to add the word `"to"` to my array. I'll be looking through a very big text file, so any notes on performance would be great too.

Comment: You could use grep for this, and it would be much easier

Comment: @meagar - so grep would get the following word into his ruby array easier than ruby?

Comment: @pguardiario Don't be obtuse. I'm suggesting it as an alternative to Ruby. We don't know what his actual problem is because he hasn't told us.

Comment: Will you need to find matches across line breaks (like if "want" is at the end of a line)? That makes a big difference.

Comment: @Max It doesn't need to be that precise. If it misses matches across line breaks, that would be okay. I actually hadn't considered grep, it might do the trick. What I'm trying to do is construct sentences from other stories.

Comment: @meagar  He's looking for a ruby solution so I assumed you were suggesting he shell out to grep, which (even if grep is there) doesn't seem easier at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most literal way to read that might look like this:

```
a = []
str = "My name is Jack and I want to go to the store"
str.scan(/\w+/).each_cons(2) {|x, y| a << y if x == 'to'}
a
  #=> ["go", "the"]
```

To read the file into a string use `File.read`.

Comment: What if it's a really big file? (Aside: can you reformat so that the reader does not have to scroll horizontally to read your code?)

Comment: @Cary You don't need permission to edit answers. Just do it if you think it's a big deal.

Comment: pg, I virtually never edit others' words. Old school, intellectual property and all that.

Comment: Well that sounds like some OCD battle. I'm going to leave it alone and see which side wins :)

Comment: You may be right about that, or maybe I'm just an old guy who is set in his ways.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

**Code**

```
def find_next(fname, word)
  enum = IO.foreach(fname)
  loop do
    e = (enum.next).scan(/\w+/)
    ndx = e.index(word)
    if ndx
      return e[ndx+1] if ndx < e.size-1
      loop do
        e = enum.next
        break if e =~ /\w+/
      end
      return e[/\w+/]
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

**Example**

```
text =<<_
It was the best of times, it was the worst of times,
it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness,
. . . . . 
it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity,
it was the season of light, it was the season of darkness,
it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair…
_

FName = "two_cities"
File.write(FName, text)

find_next(FName, "worst")
  # of
find_next(FName, "wisdom")
  # it
find_next(FName, "foolishness")
  # it
find_next(FName, "dispair")
  #=> nil
find_next(FName, "magpie")
  #=> nil
```

Shorter, but less efficient, and problematic with large files:

```
File.read(FName)[/(?<=\b#{word}\b)\W+(\w+)/,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the fastest way to do it, but something along these lines should work:

```
filename = "/path/to/filename"
target_word = "weasel"
next_word = ""

File.open(filename).each_line do |line|
  line.split.each_with_index do |word, index|
    if word == target_word
      next_word = line.split[index + 1]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a File, String, or StringIO stored in *file*:

```
pattern, match = 'want', nil
catch :found do
  file.each_line do |line|
    line.split.each_cons(2) do |words|
      if words[0] == pattern
        match = words.pop 
        throw :found
      end
    end
  end
end
match
#=> "to"
```

Note that this answer will find at most one match per file for speed, and linewise operation will save memory. If you want to find multiple matches per file, or find matches across line breaks, then [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26559384/1301972) is probably the way to go. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest I could come up with, assuming your file is loaded in a string:

```
word = 'want'
array = []
  string.scan(/\b#{word}\b\s(\w+)/) do
  array << $1
end
```

This will find ALL words that follow your particular word. So for example:

```
word = 'want'
string = 'My name is Jay and I want to go and I want a candy'
array = []
string.scan(/\b#{word}\b\s(\w+)/) do
  array << $1
end
p array #=> ["to", "a"]
```

Testing this on my machine where I duplicated this string 500,000 times, I was able to reach 0.6 seconds execution time. I've also tried other approaches like splitting the string etc. but this was the fastest solution:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report do
    word = 'want'
    string = 'My name is Jay and I want to go and I want a candy' * 500_000
    array = []
    string.scan(/\b#{word}\b\s(\w+)/) do
      array << $1
    end
  end
end
```